# Mobile Game automation testing using Appium,Opencv and Bitbar Akaze (Image Recognition)

Tags: testing, mobile, automation, appium

I want to learn how to test mobile games using Appium, so i found it could be done using Image Recognition.
I found this https://bitbar.com/appium-tip-27-using-appium-for-mobile-game-testing/
I'm truly stuck in it 
couldn't understand what i should do or add in Eclipse to test mobile games using Appium.

If anyone know how to test mobile game using Appium rather than Image Recognition please tell me.

Please, if any one have any tutorial or a clear steps of mobile game testing automation tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Appium is not a good option (unless you are ok with **image recognition approach**) to test mobile games. Appium is using native test frameworks like **UIAutomator, Espresso (Android) and XCUITest (iOS)**, that are basically implemented to test **apps build with native SDK**

Mobile games are mostly build with engines like **Unreal, Unity, Corona** ,etc. that have **no relation to native SDK** and thus **cannot be tested with native test frameworks** without additional tweaks.

Basically following issues to be addressed and add support for:

- find elements
- check action occurring in game
- check UI rendered
  properly

There are some projects where engineers are trying to use Appium with some additional ports, e.g. [Unity-Appium](https://github.com/UnityTech/GamesTestAutomationExample), but there is definitely nothing like Appium or Selenium that you can take and use like silver bullet.

Check the engine your game is based on and search for possible test frameworks.